# Android Calendar and PhoneGap

Tags: android, mobile, cordova

I want to export some data at android calendar and i'm using this code:

```
Intent calIntent = new Intent();
calIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
calIntent.setClass(this, StudysysActivity.class);

calIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
calIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "My House Party");
calIntent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "My Beach House");
calIntent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "A Pig Roast on the Beach");

GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 7, 15);
calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true);
calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
    calDate.getTimeInMillis());
calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
    calDate.getTimeInMillis());
startActivity(calIntent);
```

This code great work when i using it at my main class,but if i using this code at my second class,what interacts with javascript code - application crashed.

Second class code:

```
public class CustomNativeAccess extends DroidGap {
private WebView mAppView;
private Cursor mCursor = null;
private DroidGap mGap;
public static Context mContext;

public CustomNativeAccess(DroidGap gap, WebView view) {

    mAppView = view;
    mGap = gap;
}

public String getImeiNumber(String test) {
Intent calIntent = new Intent();
calIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
calIntent.setClass(this, StudysysActivity.class);

calIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
calIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "My House Party");
calIntent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "My Beach House");
calIntent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "A Pig Roast on the Beach");

GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 7, 15);
calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true);
calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
        calDate.getTimeInMillis());
calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
        calDate.getTimeInMillis());
startActivity(calIntent);
    String asd = test;
    return asd;
}
}
```

---

```
03-26 00:06:46.812: E/dalvikvm(30770): JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale local reference 0x35 (index 13 in a table of size 2)
03-26 00:06:46.820: E/dalvikvm(30770): VM aborting
03-26 00:06:46.820: A/libc(30770): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace errors.